# Is there a way to save RFB (vnc) streams to file? [GStreamer]

Tags: gstreamer

I am finding a way to connect to VNC and record the video using GStreamer. So far, I can connect to the VNC server but can only view the video using **autovideosink**. I wanted to save the video to a file.

This is what I tried and is working:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv rfbsrc host=127.0.0.1 width=1024 height=768 shared=true view-only=true ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1024,height=576 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

This is for saving the video file using **filesink**:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv rfbsrc host=127.0.0.1 width=1024 height=768 shared=true view-only=true ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1024,height=576 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! filesink location=video.flv
```

Results:
A file is saved with large size and is not playable.

Any inputs will be a big help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally made it. Made some changes with mov output file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv rfbsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=5900 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! qtmux ! filesink location=output.mov
```

Posted the answer for future references. Thanks.